# query with CURRENT_DATE returns 0 entries

Tags: postgresql

I've got such query

```
SELECT b.id, b.publisher_id, b.name, b.size, b.present,
       b.display, d.book_id AS download,
       b.download_date
  FROM books          b
  LEFT JOIN downloads d ON d.book_id=b.id
 WHERE b.download_date = CURRENT_DATE
 ORDER BY b.id
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

And I've got this entry in my database.

```
id(bigserial) publisher_id(bigint) name(character varying) size(bigint) present(boolean) display(boolean) download_date(timestamp with time zone)
19;1;"Attacks on and Countermeasures for USB Hardware Token Devices.rar";634764;TRUE;TRUE;"2014-06-10 08:05:28.439+00"
```

But it doesn't show the result. But today is `2014-06-10` in Windows.
What's the problem?

Comment: can you give sample data and table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timestamp` `2014-06-10 08:05:28.439+00` is not equal to the `date` `2014-06-10`. Truncate the timestamp to a day

```
WHERE date_trunc('day', b.download_date) = CURRENT_DATE

select date_trunc('day', '2014-06-10 08:05:28.439+00'::timestamp);
     date_trunc      
---------------------
 2014-06-10 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you compare a timestamp with a date. PostgreSQL won't let your data truncated, so it will convert the date to timestamp (that day's `00:00:00` time point) to do the comparison.

If you want to compare the date parts of `download_date`, you can cast it to `date` to achive a date to date comparison:

```
WHERE DATE(b.download_date) = CURRENT_DATE
```